# asp.net File Upload in published environment

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

How to upload file to the remote folder(eg:common folder where all users in the network can access) using file upload control in asp.net ?

The application I done is working well in my machine.
But in the published environment, it throws "Access to the '/common_folder_path' is denied"

Comment: Your asp.net account {MACHINE}\ASPNET does not have write access to that location. Right click on your file -> Properties -> Pop Up of User properties appears -> click on Security tab-> click on Edit -> select IIS_IUSRS-> tick on Allow Full Control -> Click Ok

Answer (score 0):

Change your application pool identity to "Network Service" and then try. If still have issue then goto that common_folder_path folder right click that folder and give rights to "Network Service" and you should able to upload